How to allow user to edit column names of a DataGridView
This post generally asks how to edit the column names of a DataGridView. Here, I'm specifically interested in allowing the user to re-name the displayed column headers themselves.
This answer points out that you have to make a custom implementation with a TextBox in order to implement this functionality.
How do you implement this?

This assumes your DataGridView is named dgv.
This allows the user to re-name on a double-click. The re-name can be cancelled by any means of de-selecting the TextBox, whether that be clicking, tabbing, etc.
This accounts for the cases where your DGV is inside other containers.
private void dgv_columnheadermousedoubleclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox temp = new TextBox();

    this.Controls.Add(temp);

    temp.Multiline = true; // allow to be vertically sized
    temp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

    // Position and size the rename box

    // This gets the bounds of the col header relative to the dgv
    Rectangle bounds = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
        e.ColumnIndex, 
        rowIndex: -1,           // -1 is the column header
        cutOverflow: false);

    // Adjust for where the DGV is on the form
    Point dgvRelativeLoc = dgv.RelativeToForm();
    bounds.X += dgvRelativeLoc.X;
    bounds.Y += dgvRelativeLoc.Y; 


    temp.Bounds = bounds;

    temp.BringToFront();
    temp.Select();       // you can start typing

    // Sets the rename using the enter key
    temp.KeyDown += (s, ea) =>
    {
        if (ea.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText = temp.Text.Trim();
            ea.Handled = true; // prevents the annoying "ding" noise
            temp.Dispose();
        }
    };

    // If the user clicks out of the textbox they can "cancel" the re-name 
    temp.Leave += (s, ea) =>
    {
        temp.Dispose();
    };
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static Point RelativeToForm(this Control control)
    {

        Form form = control.FindForm();
        if (form is null)
            return new Point(0, 0);

        Control parent = control.Parent;

        Point offset = control.Location;

        while (parent != null)
        {
            offset.X += parent.Left;
            offset.Y += parent.Top;
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }

        offset.X -= form.Left;
        offset.Y -= form.Top;

        return offset;

    }
}

